# Find roots of regression function

Tags: regression, machine-learning, signal-processing, java

Physical problem: Signal data comes from several sensors (e.g. 4) and there is empirical knowledge, that data of one of them (e.g. "productivity") depends on other data. Signals of other sensors could also depends on each other. Actually it is time series data in database.
Question: how to find, what values of sensors should be to gain certain value of "productivity".
As I see it, there should be some multi-dimensional regression (like P(x,y,z)) which could be represented as hyper-surface in (N+1 dimensional space) and the answer for the question would be roots of `P(x,y,z)=d` (where d is "desired productivity").
Am I right in this approach? Or there is more convenient method? I assume this problem is pretty general and there is some special method to solve it. Is it Machine learning problem?
Also could you recommend some framework/software (preferable in Java) for solving it.

Comment: I suggest visual inspection of scatterplots for all variables versus productivity to determine if there is any obvious data transform (such as log or exp) that will help in modeling the data.

Comment: Thanks, @JamesPhillips, but I want to find some algorithm to solve such kind of problems without any human interaction or to find out that there is no such algorithm.